# Double carriage return in importhtml to new cell

Tags: google-sheets

**Example data:**

[image: Example imported data]

**Desired formatting**

I would like for each double carriage return after the paragraphs to be split out into a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit messy but takes what was imported into B1, replaces a pair of new lines with pipe, then splits based on pipe:

```
=split(regexreplace(B1,"\n\n","|"),"|")
```